# most reusable code for submit-on-select with JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, submit

There seem to be (at least) two ways to make a JQuery datepicker submit when a date is selected. Firstly,

```
onSelect : function (dateText, inst) { $('#myFormID').submit(); }
```

from

[Post form on select with JQuery Datepick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133175/post-form-on-select-with-jquery-datepick)

or

[Datepicker Submit form when select date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171549/datepicker-submit-form-when-select-date)

The drawback with this is that it embeds the ID of the form, so if you copy the code of an existing datepicker and overlook this, it won't work; if you don't overlook it, changing the ID is still one more thing to do.

So, this version

```
onSelect : function() { $(this).parent('form').submit(); }
```

looks better as it can be copied without the need for amendment. However, if the datepicker is associated with a textbox, and the textbox is inside a table, then it won't work and this line is required instead

```
onSelect : function() { $(this).parents('form').submit(); }
```

(see [jquery datepicker won't submit inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864902/jquery-datepicker-wont-submit-inside-a-table))

The difference - just in case it's not obvious - is 'parents' not 'parent'.

I've now tried using 'parents' for all my datepickers, and they all seem to work fine - but rarely is it the recommended way to submit-on-select (e.g. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-onselect-submit-date for a non-SO example). Does anyone know a circumstance in which

```
onSelect : function() { $(this).parents('form').submit(); }
```

would not submit-on-select, or is it in fact the best and most readily reusable option?

Comment: Personally I would use `closest('form')` but since forms can't be nested the results would be the same. I don't see any reliability issues regarding what you are doing

Comment: I don't know JQuery too well. Do you mean onSelect : function() { $(this).closest('form').submit(); }

Comment: yes ... that's what i meant

Comment: Your solution works great with my dynamic datepickers in a html table.   onSelect: function(date,i) {
      if(date !== i.lastVal){
      $(this).parents('form').submit(); 
      } 
                     }